# Xcode 6 Continuous Integration Bot - Crashlytics failing on build / upload script

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, xcode-bots

Trying to incorporate Continuous Integration into my Xcode builds.
I have setup OS X Server on my MacBook and everything seems to work fine except for the actual submit/upload script for Crashlytics.

I am getting this error in the 'Trigger' log:

```
/var/folders/1d/5y5tn0hd1qj01wbxgd3sxrs4000086/T/EFFB7FF5-CFF5-41CF-8AEB-D8813069D831-16127-000004A29A1D79A7: line 2: /Crashlytics.framework/submit: No such file or directory
```

Couple things to note:

- I am able to manually archive/distribute my builds through Crashlytics without any problems.
- Crashlytics is installed via PODS and my Run Script looks like this (with my real keys obviously):

  ${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics.framework/submit MYAPIKEY MYCLIENTKEY -emails myEmail@myEmail.com -notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt -groupAliases myGroupAlias -notifications YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${PODS_ROOT}` is not available to the post trigger action.

You should use

`${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/*RepoName*/Pods/Crashlytics/Crashlytics.framework/submit` etc

Where `*RepoName*` is the name of your repo. Sadly, I haven't been able to find a env variable for it or something.

Comment: For that repo name, note that `XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR` is/will be available on Xcode 8 and later. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/EnvironmentVariableReference.html)